# How to select special rows from a dataframe and escape others iteratively?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

Let's assume there's a panda's data frame A, defined as follows:

```
df_A = pd.read_csv('A.csv') #read data
```

How to assign df_A to a new data frame df_B such that df_B selects m rows and drops n rows of df_A.

Concrete example: df_B selects 5 rows of df_A and escapes 3, selects the next 5 rows and escapes again 3, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(range(10), range(1, 11))), index=range(10))
s = pd.Series([True, False]).repeat(pd.Series({True : 5, False : 3}))
df[np.tile(s, int(np.ceil(len(df) / len(s))))[:len(df)]]

   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
3  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
4  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
8  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
9  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
```

Comment: Excuse me! Could you please add how to assign the dropped rows to a df_c? @ansev

Comment: `m = np.tile(s, int(np.ceil(len(df) / len(s))))[:len(df)]`  and  `df[~m]`

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is itter over the rows with `df_A.iterrows()` and then add five rows to df_B with `df_B.append()`

something like this:

```
i_a = 0
i_b = 0
m = 5
n = 3

for index,row in df_A.itterrows():
    i_a += 1
    if i_a >= m:
        i_b += 1
       
        if i_b >= n:
            i_a = 0
            i_b = 0

        continue

    df_B.append(row)
```

this will perform decently well depending on how large your dataframe is

Comment: Assuming df_B is df_B = pd.DataFrame(), I am facing the following error .. cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'int'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: my mistake `itterrows()` yeilds the index and the row changed the code it should work